# Master and Dev having conflict

Tags: typescript, git, azure-devops

A Developer made a PR of Branch A to make a quick fix in the Master branch, which is our QA branch. The developer has made Branch A changes to DEV environment. Now when I create DEV to MASTER PR, I get a conflict error, How do I resolve this?

I have tried merging BRANCH A to dev and it is good but when I merge dev to Master it creates an issue